# Angular: Set button text according to condtion

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my html snippet code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    {{'ui.button.edit.text' | translate}}
</button>
```

Nevertheless, I need to set button tet according to a boolean component field:

```
@Component({...})
export class UserManagementComponent {
    @Input('user')
    public set user(user: AdministrationUser) {
        this._user = user;
    };

    private get toCreate(): boolean {
        return this._user.id === null;
    }
}
```

So, I need:

- If `this.toCreate` is true button text is `{{ui.button.save.text | translate}}`,
- Otherwise, `{{ui.button.edit.text | translate}}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple ternary operator here something like

```
 {{ (toCreate ? 'ui.button.save.text' : 'ui.button.edit.text') | translate }}
```

Remove private modifier from your property as it might cause build issue in prod build

[Stackblitz eample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4g9jw)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a number of ways, I'm listing two of those here.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span *ngIf="toCreate()">{{'ui.button.save.text' | translate}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="!toCreate()">{{'ui.button.edit.text' | translate}}</span>
</button>
```

Or,

```
<button *ngIf="toCreate()" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    {{'ui.button.save.text' | translate}}
</button>
<button *ngIf="!toCreate()" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    {{'ui.button.edit.text' | translate}}
</button>
```